# webcenter content documents translate in other languages

Tags: webcenter

I am developing a portal using webcenter portal builder and I would like to ask how to translate the contents of the portal, because I have not found something relevant.

The portal is in greek and english. Following the [guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/webcenter.1111/e12405/wcadm_languages.htm#WCADM7654) I have achieved to translate the menu but for the content it only says:

> Presenting Translated Content Through a Content Presenter Template

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

They just provide you with a pointer there. Translating menus and labels is relatively easy, but for the content itself there is no standard way.

The Content Presenter is a task flow that comes out of the box with Oracle WebCenter Portal. You use it to display content that is stored in Oracle WebCenter Content as part of the portal.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/doc.1111/e27603/cont_cp.htm#WCPAA3057

By combining WebCenter Content metadata (or folder paths) with the language that is set in your portal, the suggestion is to dynamically retrieve the desired content in the correct language.

For more information please see Oracle's A-Team blog at:
http://www.ateam-oracle.com/internationalize-webcenter-portal-content-presenter/

There's also an informative post in this thread on the Oracle Forum:
https://community.oracle.com/thread/2430223